# my follower died and her dead body follows me instead

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My follower from the companions unfortunately died while on a quest. For some reason whenever I walk through a door or fast travel her dead body follows me. I can't search her body to get my dragonplate armour set back and my new housecarl (or anyone else) won't follow me because I apparently already have a follower. I'm tired of dying alone and being over encumbered. The body is face down not and moving.

Comment: Are they laying flat on the ground face down, but still move along behind you? If so I've had that, and they're not dead. Once you zone a few times it generally fixes itsself

Comment: Are you playing on PC? If you are, look up the console commands online and find the command to bring the NPC back to life.

Comment: She just wants a hug. And your brains.

Comment: This can help explain what's going on: http://comic.naver.com/webtoon/detail.nhn?titleId=350217

Comment: @Renan ...Why. Why would you do that to other people. :(

Comment: it would really help to know what platform your playing on.

Comment: This question title actually made me laugh.

Answer (score 1):

Console commands that should help (PC Only)

Select follower

```
disable
enable
```

or

```
resurrect
```